# Mac Outlook "Calendar Permissions" is grayed out

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, calendar

I'm trying to share my calendar, but the appropriate things are grayed out. To ungrey them, I'd think I need to set "Calendar Permissions". However, that's grayed out too.

I've seen things that say I need to check "Hide On My Computer folders" but that doesn't seem to do anything. Also, the options I have don't seem to match what the help pages claim. I only have:

- Show all account folders
- Hide One My Computer Folders

I don't have "Group Similar Folders".

I'm using Outlook for Mac, 15.37 in OSX 10.12.6
 on a macbook pro, in case that matters...

Comment: What year of Outlook? What version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind. It turns out I needed to actually select a specific calendar to deal with the permissions of. Once I selected a calendar, it became ungrayed.